# Realm LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection error Swift 3

Tags: swift, realm, swift3

I just updated my project to swift 3.

I am still very green in Swift features.
Anyway, i had this query's method witch was working fine,

```
func getAllPointsWithCategory(_ idCategory:String) -> [Point] {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let containingPOI = realm.objects(Point.self).filter({ (poi) -> Bool in
        return poi.categories.contains(where: { (cat) -> Bool in
            return idCategory == cat.id
        })
    })

    return containingPOI
}
```

after the update I started to receive this error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection>' to return type '[Point]'

What am I doing wrong in this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm queries return [Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html) type, not `Array`. Check https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1046 for some ways how to convert `Results` to `Array`.

Comment: Stil receiving the error, why i am getting a "LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection"? this was working with swift 2.0